# Javascript Canvas rotate image in circle axis

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, geometry

I need help, I have been trying to rotate my image which is a pointer. with my code below it rotates but it rotates not as I want.

Code:

```
  var c = document.getElementById("ctx");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    for (var d = 0; d < 360; d++) {
        setTimeout(function (d) {
            c.globalAlpha = 0.5;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(c.width / 2, c.height / 2);
            ctx.rotate(d * Math.PI / 180);
            ctx.drawImage(imageLoader.pointer, -imageLoader.pointer.width / 2, -imageLoader.pointer.height / 2);
            ctx.restore();
        }, 100 * d, d);
    }
```

This code makes my image rotate weirdly I think it rotates on its own axis but I am not sure.

However I need a rotation something like this image.

[image]

I think this rotation is around a circle, i need something like this , can someone give me a hint or help me out?

I was trying to do it with a shape but its more difficult because i need to find the tangent and more geometric formulas to make it rotate like this.

I appreciate your time in advance, thanks.

Comment: "This code makes my image rotate weirdly" <- how? Since we don't have your image, what do you mean with "weirdly"? It is recommended to use `requestAnimationFrame()` instead of starting 360 timeouts.

Comment: Like i said before " I think it rotates on its own axis but I am not sure."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to draw a rotated image rotating around a point on the canvas and offset to its own center of rotation.

```
// x,y is the location on the canvas that the image will rotate around
// cx,cy is the coordinates on the image that is rotated around
// angle is the amount of rotation in radians
function  drawImage(image,x,y,cx,cy,angle){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y);  // set the rotation origin
    ctx.rotate(angle); // rotate
    ctx.drawImage(image,-cx,-cy); // draw image offset to put cx,cy at the point of rotation
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // restore the transform
}
```

So if your image is 50 by 100 pixels and you want the image to rotate about the point on it at 25, 80 (center near bottom) and that rotation point to be on the canvas at 200,200 then

```
drawImage(image,200,200,25,80,3); //rotate 3 radians
```

To do so in an animation.

```
// assumes image has loaded and ctx is the context of the canvas.
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // starts the animation
function mainLoop(time){ // time is passed by  requestAnimationFrame
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height); // clear 
    drawImage(image,200,200,25,80,(time / 5000) * Math.PI * 2); // rotate one every 5 seconds
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```js
const image = new Image
image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=328&g=1";
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

function  drawImage(image,x,y,cx,cy,angle){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y);  // set the rotation origin
    ctx.rotate(angle); // rotate
    ctx.drawImage(image,-cx,-cy); // draw image offset to put cx,cy at the point of rotation
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // restore the transform
}


// assumes image has loaded and ctx is the context of the canvas.
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // starts the animation
function mainLoop(time){ // time is passed by  requestAnimationFrame
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height); // clear 
    if(image.complete){
        drawImage(image,250,250,image.width / 2,image.height * 0.8,(time / 5000) * Math.PI * 2); // rotate one every 5 seconds
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```css
canvas {
   border : 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width = 500 height = 500></canvas>
```